# Get XMLHttpRequest REST response in json format

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I'm trying to do a REST call to get current user information without using jQuery to handle the ajax. I've got this code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText))
        } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400){
            console.log("not found")
        } else {
            console.log("other")
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.responseType="json"
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://,site/_api/web/currentuser?$format=json",true);
xmlhttp.send()
```

This works, but the response comes back as xml not json. Is there a way to tell the SP to return json when using XHR?

I tried the `$format=json` parameter, but that evidently isn't supported by the SP 2013 REST api. Nor is XMLHttpRequest.responseType supported by browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `Accept` request header to `application/json; odata=verbose` using [XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader).

SharePoint looks at this header to decide if the data has to be sent as JSON or XML.

Comment: That seems to be working. Looking at the documentation you linked to, it looks like setRequestHeader() has support back to IE7, which is good, but is it supported in FireFox?

Comment: Hmm. Just tested. Looks like it is not working in Firefox. May be you can use a shim just for FF.